# Where are the two characters when to count with awk?

Tags: bash, awk

Here is test sample file--rime.txt.

```
file rime.txt
rime.txt: UTF-8 Unicode text
```

[rime.txt](https://github.com/michaeljamesfitzgerald/Introducing-Regular-Expressions/blob/master/rime.txt)

```
wc  -c  rime.txt
25483 rime.txt
awk '{num=num+length($0)}END{print num}' rime.txt
24648
```

length($0) contain whitespaces ,do not contain newline(0a).

```
awk 'END{print NR}' rime.txt
833
```

There are 833 **0a**--newline in rime.txt.

```
echo "25483-24648-833" |bc
2
```

Where is the two characters which awk can't count?

```
wc -m rime.txt
25481 rime.txt
```

There are two bytes which don't map any characters ,what are they?
How to find it out?

Comment: `wc -c` counts bytes, not characters. Do you have multi-byte encoding?

Comment: file rime.txt-----rime.txt: UTF-8 Unicode text

Comment: Try with `wc -m`

Comment: partly solved.  wc -m rime.txt  ----25481 rime.txt

Comment: There are two bytes which don't map any characters ,what are they?

Comment: Do a `hexdump`/`od` and check...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
wc -c rime.txt
25482 rimie.txt
wc -m  rime.txt
25480 rime.txt
grep -P "[^\x00-\x7F]" rime.txt
       That come from a far Contrée.
     And now all in mine own Countrée
awk '/[^\x00-\x7F]/{print}' rime.txt
       That come from a far Contrée.
     And now all in mine own Countrée
```

The character **é** is beyong ascii hex value,which is **e9**.
**e9** can be known by **wc -c** (bytes mode);**e9** can not be known by **wc -m** (characters mode);there are two **é**  or say **e9** in rime.txt.
So **wc -c rime.txt** get two more than **wc -m rime.txt**.

Answer (score 0):

`wc -c` counts bytes, not characters. If you have multi-byte encoding (e.g. any UTF variant) in place this would not get you the correct character count.

You need to use `wc -m` to get the character count regardless of the encoding:

```
wc -m rime.txt
```

Also as you can imagine, for ASCII character set (precisely, for all single-byte encoded characters), you would get the same count for both `wc -c` and `wc -m`.